# gulp Live reload for server side

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, livereload, gulp-browser-sync, gulp-livereload

I have a developed gulp file with both browser-sync and live reload. this gulp file works perfectly for my requirements. for the base idea, I have a root folder in my Apache server and inside it I have my project folders.

```
--public
   ---proj1
   ---proj2
```

I'm using my gulp  file to watch and build project folder and live reload.
currently I'm using browser-sync:

```
browserSync.init({
    proxy: {
          target: "localhost/newTest/public", // can be [virtual host, sub-directory, localhost with port]
          ws: true // enables websockets
      }
      });
```

every changes done inside the **'public'** folder, will affect the live reload. if I have opened both projects in two separate windows and do some changes on one project both windows are refreshing(live-reloading). I do not need that to happen. only one window should be live-reloading. how can I do it.

## reason:

I want to implement this to server side level for many users, how can I do it? A change from a user should not affect other users.

Comment: Not sure I understand but perhaps you want to start different instances of browserSync via the create() method.  And then one of those opens proj1 html file and another instance opens the proj2 html.

Comment: that won't be possible according to my gulp file :/. what if I run a gulp file per user. does it take more memory or is it bad .